# How to fetch type of the document using HstLink object

Tags: hippocms

in Hippo, I have created the  Custom Link processor class and in the preProcess method I want to fetch the type of the document through HstLink object.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't. This is just a link, and at this point it hasn't even been matched to content. In fact, the point of manipulating the link is so that it can be matched to the right content.